# How can we retrieve Kallithea admin user's Password, when forgotten it?

Tags: kallithea

How can we retrieve Kallithea admin user's Password, if forgotten it? The current setup is using its internal authentication plugin along with the default database SQLite. I can see the encrypted password in the database, but since it's encrypted, it's useless.

Answer (score 1):

As the administrator is a normal user apart from its privileges, you can use Reset Password feature to regenerate (in the current stable release) or to change (in the forthcoming 0.3 release) its password. Even if you don't have email delivery configured, just check the logs — the password reset email is dumped there when there's no email delivery.

Answer (score 0):

I think kallithea has no easy way of doing this, but when you use the original project ie. RhodeCode, there's a nice way to reset your account.

https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/admin/reset-information.html#manually-reset-password